# Do reports from the UK show that Covid-19 vaccines had a higher mortality rate among children than the Covid Virus in 2021?

Tags: covid-19, statistics

According to OAN, between January and December 2021 the covid-19 vaccine had a higher mortality rate among children than the covid virus (see linked video for full content):

> Reports from the UK Government and the CDC reveal that the vaccines for the virus are killing far more children than the virus itself.

[Source](https://rumble.com/vuma7u-cdc-data-reveals-vaccines-are-killing-far-more-children-than-china-virus-it.html)

> According to data released by [the ONS], children who get injected by
> the China Virus Vaccine suffer a death rate 52 times than children who
> aren't given the Communist vaccine.

[Source](https://rumble.com/vuma7u-cdc-data-reveals-vaccines-are-killing-far-more-children-than-china-virus-it.html)

[image]

Are the claims made in this video accurate?

Comment: I could have sworn we handled this question already on this site, but I seem to be striking out.  Writing answer now.  Tl;dr vaccinated children in 2021 in the UK were medically at risk children and cohort death totals were statistically unchanged from previous and future years.

Comment: We very much prefer to deal with only one claim at once. This question has two - the UK mortality and the Chinese vaccine figures. Could we create separate questions for them?

Comment: @DJClayworth I think, when the video uses the phrase "China Virus Vaccine", they're not saying "the Chinese vaccine for COVID-19", but using the term "China Virus" as the derogatory form of COVID-19.

Comment: @DenisS, this exact claim (referencing the ONS report), or a generic claim about mortality rates? I didn't get anything in the auto-suggest one the title, I'm more interested in the exact figure in the video as it's referencing a UK government report, not making an unsourced accusation.

Comment: @DenisS, my experience is that questions about vaccinations data seem to get a more political reaction than other topics, so it's possible that the questions were deleted. Political topics tend to attract unusual ire.

Comment: @DenisS I was looking at "Communist vaccine", but I guess in AntiVaxx speak that just means "vaccine inflicted upon us by the evil godless communists who are in charge in the US". :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Reuters examined similar claims in October 2022 and found the claims to be false.  While vaccinated children in 2021 did have a higher death rate than children dying of COVID during the same time period, this was a result of the UK vaccination policy that prioritized medically at risk children.**

---

Reuters [examined the claim](https://www.reuters.com/article/factcheck-vaccinedeaths-children/fact-check-covid-19-vaccines-not-linked-to-8200-increase-in-child-deaths-in-past-year-as-claimed-in-online-video-idUSL1N31K0ZE) in a 19 October 2022 article titled "Fact Check-COVID-19 vaccines not linked to 8,200% increase in child deaths in past year, as claimed in online video".

> COVID-19 vaccines have not caused an 8,200% increase in child deaths between 2021 and 2022, as has been claimed in a video posted on social media. That figure “completely misrepresents data”, according to a UK Office for National Statistics (ONS) spokesperson.

> The footage, posted on Facebook here, shows a man in military uniform addressing an audience outside a COVID-19 vaccination centre in Windsor that he and other protesters had attempted to close down on Oct. 11.

> During a five-minute speech, he claimed (at 1:34): “There is an 8,200% death increase in our children this year. So, from 2021 to 2022 there was an 8,200% death increase in our children. Mine and yours. The vaccines are not safe, and they are not effective.”

While this is not the same source as quoted by OP, the statements are similar enough to be considered equal.

An ONS spokeperson spoke to Reuters via email while writing the article.

> “There has not been an 8,200% increase in child deaths between 2021 and 2022,” based on weekly data through early October (here), the spokesperson said. Comparing total deaths over the same period across the last three years shows that “from week 1 to week 39 in 2020, there were 2,419 deaths registered for 0-14-year-olds. Based on weekly data, from week 1 to week 39 in 2021, there were 2,415 deaths registered for 0-14-year-olds. Based on weekly data, from week 1 to week 39, in 2022 there were 2,496 deaths registered for 0-14-year-olds.”

Per data from 2022 and 2020, there has been very little change in death totals amongst 0-14 year olds.

---

So where does the 8200% increase claim come from?  The article goes on to elaborate (emphasis mine).

> Addressing the claim in The Exposé about an increase in the risk of death in children who are vaccinated, the spokesperson added that the ONS has “always said **mortality rates should be interpreted carefully for children because of the way children at risk were prioritised in the vaccine rollout**” and because “**rates vary considerably due to the relatively low number of deaths in these age categories**”.

> **Children with underlying health conditions who were most at risk from COVID-19 were first in line to be vaccinated in the UK beginning in late 2021 and early 2022 ([here](https://www.reuters.com/world/uk/britain-approves-pfizer-biontech-shot-younger-children-2021-12-22/) and [here](https://www.reuters.com/business/healthcare-pharmaceuticals/britain-offer-covid-vaccinations-vulnerable-children-aged-5-11-2022-01-30/)).**

> “**Clinically vulnerable children and young people have higher mortality rates than those with no comorbidities, and this explains why vaccinated children have a higher rate of death than those who remained unvaccinated**,” the spokesperson said.

> However, “there is no evidence of the vaccine having an effect on death rates,” they added, citing tables 12 and 13 on the monthly spreadsheets available at this ONS webpage ([here](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/birthsdeathsandmarriages/deaths/datasets/monthlymortalityanalysisenglandandwales)), which illustrate the rarity of deaths linked to COVID-19 vaccination at any age, and only one involving a child in the UK.

In the most recent spreadsheet tally of deaths between March 2020 and August 2022 ([here](https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/peoplepopulationandcommunity/birthsdeathsandmarriages/deaths/datasets/monthlymortalityanalysisenglandandwales/august2022/monthlymortalityanalysisaug2022.xlsx)), a total of 54 deaths in all age groups are attributed to “COVID-19 vaccines causing adverse effects in therapeutic use” (table 12), and of these, a single death occurred in the 10-19 age group while there were none among younger children (table 13).

---

In conclusion:

- Death rates amongst children aged 0-13 in the UK have not changed significantly in the years prior to or after the Vaccine rollout to children in the UK.
- A higher mortality rate amongst children who received the vaccine in 2021 is a result of the UK prioritizing medically at risk children before the general public
- These medically at risk children have a naturally higher chance of death due to existing health problems
- Of the 54 confirmed vaccine complications since the rollout began, only a single person under the age of 20 has been found to have died due to the vaccine, and none  under the age of 10.

Comment: Short answer = the figures are real, but are in the context of the vaccine only being given to specific children?

Comment: Does the Reuter's article address this exact claim, or a similar claim made by someone else?

Comment: @AaarghZombies it's about exactly the same table that details the deaths by vaccination status and age from the UK.

Comment: @Mad Scientist, I haven't read through it fully yet, but the take-away seems different (or at least the math), so it may be closely related. I will see what other answers are provided.

Comment: @AaarghZombies it's the same set of tables, but the claims use different time frames and comparisons. All the arguments against both claims are the same, they're using raw data that simply does not mean what they are claiming. There were 7 deaths among vaccinated children in that timeframe, and they're directly comparing them against the deaths of unvaccinated children without correcting for anything. And the data does not indicate at all whether the deaths had anything to do with the vaccine.

Comment: Another possible “good” reason for more deaths from vaccine vs illness: if you achieve herd immunity then you have zero deaths from illness, and probably some deaths in car accidents going to/coming from their vaccination alone. Not what happened with Covid though.

Comment: @AaarghZombies specifically, only very sick kids were getting the vaccine, sick kids tend to die more than healthy kids regardless, they were comparing "sick kids who got the vaccine and died at some point" vs "all kids who died from covid"

Comment: @AaarghZombies while the Reuters claim is addressing someone else's claim and not these rumble videos, the basis of both claims is the same, that "children who died after being vaccinated in 2021 died at a higher rate than children from COVID over the same period".  And the refutation is the same, namely that "children who were vaccinated in 2021 were supposed to have a higher death rate than children from COVID because they were VERY sick".  Healthy children weren't getting the vaccine in 2021.

Comment: It should also be noted that the rumble (originally OANN) videos were posted in Feb 2022, whereas the claims addressed in the Reuters video were from October 2022.  Presumably, the data would be better in October than in February, and it's highly likely that the claims addressed in the October videos are based on the claims from the February videos

Comment: Take polio. Without vaccination thousands and thousands of kids would die every year. With vaccination the polio deaths are zero. There are probably more than zero kids doing in car accidents on the way getting their vaccination alone. So it is quite possible that a vaccine kills more than the illness (when everyone is vaccinated), yet the vaccination is very positive overall.

Comment: I looked at this myself. The time frame cut-off was before general vaccination of children. What these numbers show is that kids with cancer die more than kids who don't have it, because only the desperately ill children were vaccinated.